# how to trigger mouse wheel click with protractor

Tags: protractor, click, mouse

I'm testing an Angular 14 app with protractor 7 e2e tests.

I want to emulate a middle mouse (wheel) click on an element.
How do I do this ?

Thanks.

(A different solution using Webdriver, pure Javascript, ... is fine too)

Answer (score 0):

For the record:

```
await browser.actions().click(element, Button.MIDDLE).perform();
```